# Mule ESB: Maven build fails on /nexus path when trying to deploy Mule project to Cloudhub through Command prompt

Tags: mule, mule-studio, cloudhub

I'm trying to deploy Mule project to cloudhub using command prompt. I'm getting the below error:

```
" Illegal path attribute "/nexus". Path of origin: "/snapshots/org/mule/modules/mule-module-    cloudhub/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mule-module-cloudhub-3.0.0-20140909.225040-1.pom"
```

I have tried to remove repository for nexus, but I got the same error. Also referred the url

- [Connection to http://dev.ee.mulesource.com refused: Operation timed out](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/connection_to_http_dev_ee_mulesource_com_refused_operation_timed_out)
- [Why do Mule Studio 3.4 Builds with Maven Fail or Hangs Indefinitely?](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/why_do_mule_studio_3_4_builds_with_maven_fail_or_hangs_indefinitely)

But, when I try to deploy using anypoint GUI, it is being deployed in cloudhub. Problem arises when it comes to console.

[image]
Please find my pom repository for Nexus

```
<repository>
        <id>mule-ee-releases</id>
        <name>Mule Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/ci-releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

<pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>org.mule.tools</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>

<servers>
 <server>
<id>cloudhub.io</id>
<username>my_UserName</username>
<password>PWD</password>
 </server>
</servers>
</settings>
```

Comment: You are mixing stuff. Maven servers are for configuring credentials to Maven repositories, in this case you are using a MuleSoft private repository. CloudHub is an IPaaS provider, you don't use maven-deploy-plugin to deploy applications to it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot, it seems you are trying to deploy your project to https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/snapshots/ You apparently haven't provided the credentials to connect to this server so you can't upload your build artifacts there.

You need to either:

- provide credentials that authorize you to deploy to `repository-master.mulesoft.org`, via: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers
- deploy to another repository where you are authorized to do so, via: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have the credential for cloudhub, added the same in settings.xml(/.m2). Apart from this to deploy things in cloudhub i dont think we need a credentials. Currently i'm not using nexus. Even i have tried removing the nexus repository from POM. Still it is throwing error. Could you please guide me.

Comment: Do you have any entry in the distribution management section of your POM or its parent POM, if any?

Comment: This is the parent POM. I have valid credentials. I'm following this link [link](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/using-continuous-deployment-with-cloudhub/), but application not being deployed in Cloudhub

Comment: The example you linked doesn't specify to use a parent POM and doesn't configure distribution management towards MuleSoft's private repo. I think you should carefully review your POM to remove all the unecessary bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a reverse proxy and you have different context paths on either side of it you'll need to map cookies as well.

For **Apache** you can use:
*`ProxyPassReverseCookiePath    /nexus /`*

For **Nexus** you can use:
*`proxy_cookie_path    /nexus /;`*